# Getting r_fullprofile access to the Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am currently using a linkedin API with r_lightprofile in my application.

Two months ago, I sent a request for access to r_fullprofile using the Partner Program form. 
https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/contact-us
http://prntscr.com/opfnpd
I also sent a request to the Marketing Developer Platform, but the request is still pending (http://prntscr.com/opfvfx)
After all this, I got an email with a form to fill out information about the company. 
But after filling out the form, I did not receive an answer that the company is suitable or not suitable for full access.

1) How long does it usually take to get access?

2) Does the linkedin API have support? Email, Live chat or something else?

3) Have I done everything for access? Maybe I missed something?

4) Does Linkedin send an email in case of failure?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a long way for me too, I'll give you some random tips:

- Make sure your app is connected to a LinkedIn company page and that the status is **Verified**. To do this, from the app dashboard, add to the Team members an administrator of the LinkedIn company page (as Admin member) and let him access the app dashboard. He should be able to see a Verify button to confirm the authenticity of the app.
- The only support that was really helpful to me was [Zendesk](https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us).

Comment: Yes. I Verified my application. 
Thanks a lot for the link. I will try send request

Comment: @Alena You ever get approved or any reply/feedback from the LinkedIn team?

Comment: @devon-bernard Yes, I got answers. I was denied two times. 
First time when I received a link to Zendesk. The second time after half a year.
In both cases, I got the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api-v1-migration

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Alena. I heard back from their Zendesk, they said "With the migration of API permissions from V1 to V2, we removed the ability to access full profile data.  Unfortunately, r_fullprofile is not being granted at this time and there are no immediate plans to change the provisioning of the permission."

So it seems r_fullprofile access is going to be impossible going forward, probably because they want to limit competitors. Too bad, now I feel pre-populating someone's professional history is going to be a more painful process.